# Info callback in CPLEX OPL

Tags: cplex, callback, opl

Does CPLEX OPL provides support for *info* callback? By *info* callback I am referring to callback allowing to retrieve information of the current solution at a given step of the optimization process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of if *informational callbacks* can be invoked directly via `OPl-CPLEX` the same as the low-level programming language. For more details, you can check [*What informational callbacks can return*](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=callbacks-what-informational-can-return) on the IBM host. As far as I know, to access some low-level information in OPL, you have two ways.

1- Using the `Main` block to call some functions like:

```
main {         
opl.postProcess();        
writeln("Current solution : ", cplex1.getObjValue()); 
}
```

2- linking OPL with a low-level language like Java to call some functions:

```
IloOplModel opl = oplF.createOplModel(def, cplex);
opl.generate();
cplex.solve();
System.out.println("OBJECTIVE: " + opl.getCplex().getObjValue());
opl.postProcess();
opl.printSolution(System.out);
```

For the first way [TSP by adding a lazy constraint](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/tsp.mod) and for the second `distMIP` example on the `C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio201\opl\examples\opl_interfaces\java` might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful!

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade, your welcome and I am glad it helps.